# O que é uma modal?

Tags: terminologia, modal, ui

Comecei a dar manutenção a um projeto que não é meu, em ASP.NET e C#. mas creio que sirva para outras linguagens também. Em algumas ações de botões aparece esse termo "modal" e estou na dúvida do que seja.

Comment: Modal é uma espécie de pop-up. Esse link pode te ajudar https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/

Comment: É a janelinha de mensagem que deixa a tela opaca.

Comment: Relacionada: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/351410/quais-as-diferen%C3%A7as-entre-lightbox-e-modal-box/

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Modal é uma tela (janela) que bloqueia a tela (janela) principal. Ela abre em cima de uma tela e não permite que se interaja com a tela parente enquanto não concluir a ação que a tela modal quer que você faça, o que pode ser só para dar um ok (ou cancelar em alguns casos), passar um tempo até ler, ou eventualmente preencher com alguns dados. Fica claro que esta tela só existe por causa da outra e é filha dela.

Ela tende manter um diálogo momentâneo com o usuário, por isso costuma ser uma *dialog box* e muitas pessoas confundem os dois termos e acham que uma coisa é a outra. Um modal não precisa ser uma caixa de diálogo e uma caixa de diálogo pode ser *modeless* (o oposto de modal).

A tela principal não desaparece enquanto está na modal, apenas fica sem poder acessar, de fato é possível ver o que está lá e isto pode ser útil. É comum poder deslocar a modal de lugar (em geral é uma tela menor) para desobstruir a visão.

Algumas pessoas consideram ela um mau uso de UI e atrapalha a experiência do usuário. Alguns [erros que podem acontecer são apresentados na Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mode_(user_interface)#Mode_errors) (talvez eu traga pra cá depois). Uma tela *modeless* pode dar mais flexibilidade, mas também tem seu lado ruim permitindo a pessoa fazer o que não deve.

Já vi telas modais mal feitos entrar em uma espécie de *deadlock* :)

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Estava ficando preocupado que o pessoal estava usando web pra dar exemplo de modal. Positivei e estou comentando pois o bloqueio da "tela pai" é o aspecto que sempre passa batido e deve ser destacado para futuros leitores.

Answer (score 8):

Uma janela ou caixa de diálogo *modal* é um elemento da interface de usuário que exige uma resposta do operador do software, não permitindo nenhuma outra ação até que essa resposta seja dada. Um exemplo clássico são os diálogos de salvamento: ou você salva o arquivo, ou cancela a operação de salvamento. Enquanto o usuário não fizer uma dessas ações, a caixa de diálogo não é fechada, impedindo qualquer outra ação.

Answer (score -2):

**Modal**, nada mais é do que uma caixa de alerta personalizada, contendo informações para uma determinada ação.

No exemplo que você deu, ao clicar em um botão, pode ser uma confirmação de deleção, por exemplo:

"Deseja mesmo excluir esse usuário?" Opções: Sim, Cancelar

Você pode ter mais informações a respeito deste componente [aqui](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/modal/).

---

**Edit:** esta resposta toma uma visão simplista de modal, resumindo-a à uma simples caixa de diálogo. Conforme comentários nesta resposta e conteúdo de outras respostas, existem outros pontos que diferenciam um modal de uma *dialog box*.

Comment: Esta é a definição de *dialog box*.

Comment: No próprio site do Bootstrap, os exemplos mostram uma "Dialog box". Favor embasar sua resposta, antes de simplesmente negativar.

Comment: Acho que você não entendeu o apontamento do colega. Modal é um tipo específico de caixa de diálogo, mas sua resposta trata do caso genérico.

Comment: Eu não negativei, mas você deve embasar sua resposta. O que tem no site do Bootstrap é um exemplo como você mesmo percebe. Um modal pode ser um *dialog* box, mas nem sempre. E o que define um modal não é ser um alerta como está na sua resposta, é o fato dela ser bloqueante. A doc do Bootstrap é muito falho nisso e não tem o que você postou como resposta. De qq forma o que eles chamam de modal lá é um termo ruim e mal usado, e a pergunta não é sobre Bootstrap, o fato de você só conhecer o termo nesse contexto só indica que não deveria responder.

Comment: Eu esperava uma primeira resposta como esta sua segunda, vindo de alguém com tamanha reputação. Obrigado por embasar melhor a resposta.