# "alert()”, “confirm()” e “prompt()” são considerados más práticas?

Tags: javascript, modal, ux, ui

Onde trabalho alguns profissionais não gostam de utilizar estes recursos e disseram que são considerados má prática e que foram alertados por outros programados mais experientes a não fazer uso e acabam substituindo estas funções por janelas modais.

Eles estavam certos em relação isso, devemos evitar? O mais indicado é fazer uso de janela modal para realizar estas operações?

```
window.prompt("sometext","defaultText");
    
alert("I am an alert box!");

function myFunction() {
   var txt;
   if (confirm("Press a button!")) {
            txt = "You pressed OK!";
   } else {
            txt = "You pressed Cancel!";
   }
   document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = txt;
}
```

Comment: São ferramentas toscas, de aparência muito antiprofisisonal, devem se restringir ao uso para debug.

Comment: @epx na verdade é exatamente o oposto. Elas não foram criadas para debug e são utilizadas erroneamente para tal por preguiça do desenvolvedor. `alert` você usa quando deseja criar um alerta, `confirm` quando deseja confirmar algo e `prompt` quando deseja solicitar algo; para debug deve-se usar ferramentas de debug. Esses itens só não são mais utilizados porque não permitem personalização.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Não é que seja má prática, até porque boa ou má prática é desculpa de quem não sabe o que está fazendo. Pensa bem, o que significa boa prática? Uma receita de bolo que alguém mandou você fazer porque alguém praticou assim e disse que é bom, o que isso é útil para o aprendizado?

Estas janelas são [modais](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/419766/101) então a pergunta parte de uma premissa errada. Você pode substituir esse modal por outro modal criado com HTML/CSS e manipulada com JS, desta forma você pode dar o visual que quiser e tem possibilidade de manipular de forma bastante flexível. Isto é uma prática melhor que usar o que o *browser* te dá pronto? Em alguns cenários sim, fica mais bonito e melhora a experiência do usuário, em outros não faz tanta diferença e só dá mais trabalho.

Fazer o certo e o errado para o cenário é a única boa prática que deve seguir, então tem que entender o todo, ganhar experiência para tomar decisões certas e não seguir receitas prontas. A maioria dos softwares que vemos por aí são ruins porque seguem boas práticas, parece incoerente, mas é isso, as pessoas usam a ferramenta certa para a tarefa errada.

[image: Cavalo no banco de trás de um carro com a cabeça pra fora]

Este não é um caso que ficará terrível, mas tem muitos casos que fica ruim, funciona e as pessoas não percebem o quanto é ruim. Quantas vezes você já viu algo claramente ruim e se perguntou porque alguém que você sabe que fez e tem experiência fez algo assim?

É feio usar o modal do *browser*, mas por que seria uma prática ruim? Se não atende a necessidade é ferramenta errada e não má prática. Os requisitos é que devem determinar isso.

- Precisa manter um padrão estético da página?
- Precisa de um comportamento diferente do que tem pronto?
- Consegue fazer algo melhor e bem feito?
- Tem tempo para fazer algo melhor?

Esses são fatores para decidir usar o seu próprio mecanismo. Se for para fazer um pior então esse é bom.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Achei uma resposta tão subjetiva e abstrata. Ao mesmo tempo achei uma resposta excelente. Vai entender ... Rs

Comment: A pergunta foi considerada subjetiva.

Answer (score 9):

Não são más práticas, até porque ainda continuam na linguagem, acredito que podemos dizer de outra forma: *"não use alert, confirm e prompt, porque atualmente existem outras formas de fazer que ficam mais em acordo com o layout do site e temos mais controle"*.

**Por que o layout do site?**

Porque não é possível estilizar as janelas desses comandos, eles são gerados pelo motor no navegador, então pode ficar bem estranho um `alert` por exemplo aqui no layout do *Stackoverflow*. Se clicar ai no link "Sinalizar" vai ver uma janela, que claro é bem mais complexa que um simples `alert` ou qualquer dos outros comandos, mas pode ver que a janela está totalmente aderente ao layout do site, porque é uma forma de janela/modal/popup/alert qualquer coisa que queira feita com código javascript/html/css, ou seja, se pode deixar com o layou que deseja.

**Por que mais controle?**

Seguindo o mesmo exemplo acima, do link "Sinalizar", é possível controlar o comportamento da janela, por exemplo mudar de cor ao clicar em alguma opção, abrir ou janela sobre essa enquanto ela ainda está abeta, etc. Esses e outros comportamentos não seriam possíveis com os comandos da sua pergunta, porque como dito, eles são controlados pelo motor do navegador, e o controle sobre eles é bem limitado, assim com o layout.

Portanto, pode até dizer que não são boas práticas, mas prefiro pensar em "existem outras formas melhores de fazer".

Uma *má prática* seria fazer mal uso de alguma coisa, por exemplo usar o `getElementsByTagName`, selecionar todos os elementos do tipo `div` e procurar um com o ID "teste", sendo que para isso existe o `getElementByID`.